# Shibboleth IdP won't start with Jetty 9.3

Tags: java, jetty, shibboleth, saml

I've been following [this guide](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/Jetty93) to install Shibboleth Identity Provider 3.3.2 on Jetty 9.3.22 (Ubuntu Server 16.04 with Oracle JDK 8u151).

**At https://my.server.ip/idp I get a 503 error (`Service Unavailable`).**

- Jetty Home: `/opt/jetty/jetty-distribution` (symlinked to
  `jetty-distribution-9.3.22.v20171030` in the same directory)
- Jetty Base: `/opt/jetty/jetty-base`
- Shibboleth Installation: `/opt/shibboleth-idp`

I've created a `jetty` user and I'm using [setuid](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/setting-port80-access.html) to bind to ports 80 and 443. `jetty:jetty` owns everything under `/opt/jetty/` and `/opt/shibboleth-idp`

Logs and configs below, though the configs are mostly a copy/paste from the instructions. I've also configured logback per the instructions, but that seems to be working, so I won't include the config unless necessary.

I should also note that I have not begun configuring Shibboleth. As I understand, I should still at least be able to run this command and get some results:

```
root@shib:/opt/shibboleth-idp/bin# ./status.sh 
(http://localhost/idp/status) Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://localhost/idp/status
```

Before even navigating to any URL, I get this in `/opt/jetty/jetty-base/log/jetty.log` upon starting the jetty service:

```
    19:55:27.983 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext:531] - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@23a5fd2{/idp,[file:///opt/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-80-idp.war-_idp-any-1528794646328615543.dir/webinf/, jar:file:///opt/shibboleth-idp/war/idp.war!/],UNAVAILABLE}{/opt/shibboleth-idp/war/idp.war}
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:539)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:448)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:496)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1363)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1540)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1462)
            Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiReleaseJarFile.<init>(MultiReleaseJarFile.java:92)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:926)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:890)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:551)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
            Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiReleaseJarFile.<init>(MultiReleaseJarFile.java:92)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:926)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:890)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:551)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
                    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiReleaseJarFile.<init>(MultiReleaseJarFile.java:92)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:926)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:890)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:551)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    19:55:27.989 - INFO [org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:278] - Started ServerConnector@16f7c8c1{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:80}
    19:55:28.273 - INFO [org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory:290] - x509=X509@1e683a3e(1,h=[example.com],w=[example.com]) for SslContextFactory@2053d869(file:///opt/shibboleth-idp/credentials/idp-browser.p12,null)
    19:55:28.335 - INFO [org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:278] - Started ServerConnector@2f0a87b3{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:443}
    19:55:28.335 - INFO [org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:414] - Started @4819ms
```

`/etc/default/jetty`

```
JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty/jetty-distribution
JETTY_BASE=/opt/jetty/jetty-base
JETTY_LOGS=/var/log/jetty
```

`/opt/jetty/jetty-base/start.ini`

```
# To disable the warning message, comment the following line
--module=home-base-warning

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: ext
--module=ext

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: resources
--module=resources

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: server
--module=server

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: http
--module=http

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: deploy
--module=deploy

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: jsp
--module=jsp

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: websocket
--module=websocket

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: jstl
--module=jstl

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: annotations
--module=annotations

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: logging
--module=logging

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: requestlog
--module=requestlog

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: servlets
--module=servlets

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: plus
--module=plus

# ---------------------------------------
# Mwdule: http-forwarded
--module=http-forwarded

--exec
--skip-file-validation=ssl
-XX:+UseG1GC
-Xmx1500m
-Djava.io.tmpdir=tmp
-Djava.library.path=libsetuid-linux
-Didp.home=/opt/shibboleth-idp
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom
```

`/opt/jetty/jetty-base/webapps/idp.xml`

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="idp.home"/>/war/idp.war</Set>
  <Set name="contextPath">/idp</Set>
  <Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
  <Set name="copyWebDir">false</Set>
  <Set name="copyWebInf">true</Set>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem today. After some more research, [this Jetty bug](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1797) seemed related to my issue. The patch didn't make the Jetty 9.3.22 release, so I built the latest 9.3.x branch from source and I'm using that now.

So, that is:

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project.git
cd jetty.project
git checkout --track origin/jetty-9.3.x
mvn clean install
```

After building, copy and extract `./jetty-distribution/target/jetty-distribution-9.3.23-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz` to your desired location.